# Images getting downloaded by 'a' tag

Tags: html

I've met with a pretty weird problame. I just want to create a simple gallery, but when I tryin out this simple code row: : `<a href="images/2.JPG"><img src="images/2small.JPG"></a>` the image is  getting downloaded, instead of open the bigger picture.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <a href="images/2.JPG" target="_blank">
   <img src="images/2small.JPG">
 </a>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

Use `target="_blank"`

`target` specifies where to display the linked URL, as the name for a browsing context

`_blank`: usually a new tab, but users can configure browsers to open a new window instead.

[Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-target)

```html
<a href="https://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_trulli.jpg" target="_blank">
  <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_trulli.jpg" alt=""></a>
```